# Using Python Play-Scraper Module - Cannot retrieve data using module

Tags: python, google-play

Here is the link to the module:https://github.com/danieliu/play-scraper

I am looking to scrape a collection from the google play store for a project.

I run the following code.

```
import play_scraper
print play_scraper.collection(
        collection='COMMUNICATION',
        category='TOP COMMUNICATION APPS',
        results=5,
        page=1
```

Traceback:

```
SyntaxError: in File "Play-scrape.py", line 2, in <module>
             print  play_scraper.collection(
                             ^
```

**Update**

I use python3 when running code and updated my print statements to include brackets.

Now I receive the error

```
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 144, got 128
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 144, got 128
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 144, got 128
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 144, got 128
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 144, got 128
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 144, got 128
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 144, got 128
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grequests.py:21: MonkeyPatchWarning: Monkey-patching ssl after ssl has already been imported may lead to errors, including RecursionError on Python 3.6. It may also silently lead to incorrect behaviour on Python 3.7. Please monkey-patch earlier. See https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1016. Modules that had direct imports (NOT patched): ['urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py)', 'urllib3.util (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py)']. 
  curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Play-scrape.py", line 9, in <module>
    print (play_scraper.search('dogs', page=2))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/play_scraper/api.py", line 79, in search
    return s.search(query, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/play_scraper/scraper.py", line 481, in search
    response = send_request('POST', self._search_url, data, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/play_scraper/utils.py", line 124, in send_request
    allow_redirects=allow_redirects)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 503, in request
    prep.url, proxies, stream, verify, cert
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 676, in merge_environment_settings
    env_proxies = get_environ_proxies(url, no_proxy=no_proxy)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 760, in get_environ_proxies
    if should_bypass_proxies(url, no_proxy=no_proxy):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 744, in should_bypass_proxies
    bypass = proxy_bypass(parsed.hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 2610, in proxy_bypass
    return proxy_bypass_macosx_sysconf(host)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 2587, in proxy_bypass_macosx_sysconf
    return _proxy_bypass_macosx_sysconf(host, proxy_settings)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 2560, in _proxy_bypass_macosx_sysconf
    hostIP = socket.gethostbyname(hostonly)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gevent/_socketcommon.py", line 163, in gethostbyname
    return get_hub().resolver.gethostbyname(hostname)
  File "src/gevent/_hub_local.py", line 73, in gevent.__hub_local.get_hub_noargs
  File "src/gevent/_hub_local.py", line 80, in gevent.__hub_local.get_hub_noargs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 390, in __init__
    WaitOperationsGreenlet.__init__(self, None, None)
  File "src/gevent/_greenlet_primitives.py", line 42, in gevent.__greenlet_primitives.TrackedRawGreenlet.__init__
SystemError: /Users/sysadmin/build/v3.7.0/Objects/dictobject.c:1439: bad argument to internal function
```

I am new to python and scripts, and any advice on how to move forward on this issue would be much appreciated. I know this a basic problem and apologise if it's easily answerable elsewhere.

-- NOTE: Originally helped on syntax because I was not adding in the bracket in accordance to python3 syntax and was receiving a syntax error. I now return this error in my terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably on python 3.x, where [print statements need brackets](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html)

try

```
print(play_scraper.collection(
      collection='COMMUNICATION',
      category='TOP COMMUNICATION APPS',
      results=5,
      page=1))
```

For your second issue

try running

```
pip3 install play-scraper -U
```

To make sure you have the latest requirements. Note `pip -> python2.x, pip3 -> python3.X`

Comment: I just ran the code now and I go the same issue and the terminal also returned the same syntax error. Am I running the module completely wrong? In theory, does it look correct the code I am running to extract data via the module?

Comment: on your terminal run `python --version`,  if you have `3.x.x`, put brackets on all you print statements! This is a `SyntaxError ` and has nothing to do with `play_scraper`

Comment: Ok, just ran version and I have 2.7.10 - I'll install now the latest version.

Comment: I have updated the original question because I now receive a new error after improving formatting.

Comment: You should upvote if this helped you first question. Then i can help on the next

Comment: Hi - I am upvoting but my reputation is so low because I'm new on the site it won't log the upvote. It said the upvote has been logged but unfortunately won't show. I'm sorry, I wish I could be more help.

Comment: not a problem, i updated your question to keep the context of the first one

Comment: I ran the upgrade and I got a succession of text strings in the terminal returning Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: pycparser in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7->cryptography>=1.3.4; extra == "security"->requests[security]>=2.9.1->play-scraper) (2.18)